# MySQL server has gone away even after increasing max packet to 128M?

Tags: sql, database, mysql, my.cnf

I edited my max packet in **my.cnf** to 128M and I still receive:

> error 2006 MySQL server has gone away

when trying to dump a large file. I also restarted MySQL service as well.

I can't figure out why this is happening.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Fixed error formatting

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tryed to use an higher value like 256M?

```
max_allowed_packet= 256M
```

Do you have `wait_timeout` setted in your my.cnf?

If not add

```
wait_timeout= 6000
```

Save and restart mysql.
Let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have tried both of these as well. I tried all the way up to 1024M and never seem to made a difference, also added a timeout. Still get error 2006.

Comment: How do you dump the file? Someone other use db when you try the dump? Could you post some code?

Comment: I'm just dragging the .sql file into the query window and it gives me two options. Run directly or load into editor which takes too much memory to do so I just choose run directly.

Comment: Have you SSH access to your Server? you could try this `mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < filename.sql`

Comment: I'll try this later once I can get to my computer, do you have any other ideas if I can't try this?

Comment: Yeah couldn't get that to work, says it cant find the file but Im not sure if Im even doing the command right.

Comment: Ok suppose that in the FILE.sql you have some CREATE TABLE or INSERT INTO. You have to go in the folder where do you have stored the file and then `mysql -u username -ppassword databasename < ./filename.sql`

Comment: I tried again, this is what my command looks like `mysql -u root -ppassword world < ./TDB.sql` and I get the error `The system cannot find the file specified` Also I cd'd into the directory that has the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72177/discussion-between-gmazzacua-and-brejuro).